# Return more that one ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to deal with this [baking JSON](https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json):

in android app so this is the class to bring the JSON data from link:

**OpenBakingJsonUtils.java:**

```
    public final class OpenBakingJsonUtils {

    public static ArrayList<ArraysLists> getSimpleBakingStringsFromJson(Context context, String bakingJsonString)
            throws JSONException {

        final String ID = "id";
        final String NAME = "name";
        final String SERVINGS = "servings";
        final String INGREDIENTS = "ingredients";
        final String STEPS = "steps";
        final String QUANTITY = "quantity";
        final String MEASURE = "measure";
        final String INGREDIENT = "ingredient";
        final String IDSTEPS = "id";
        final String SHORTDESCRIPTION = "shortDescription";
        final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
        final String VIDEOURL = "videoURL";
        final String THUMBNAILURL = "thumbnailURL";

        ArrayList<ArraysLists> parsedRecipeData = new ArrayList<ArraysLists>();

        ArrayList<BakingItem> Baking = new ArrayList<BakingItem>();
        JSONArray recipeArray = new JSONArray(bakingJsonString);

        for (int i = 0; i < recipeArray.length(); i++) {
            int id;
            String name;
            int servings;
            double quantity;
            String measure;
            String ingredient;
            int idSteps;
            String shortDescription;
            String description;
            String videoURL;
            String thumbnailURL;

            JSONObject recipeObject = recipeArray.getJSONObject(i);
            id = recipeObject.getInt(ID);
            name = recipeObject.getString(NAME);
            servings = recipeObject.getInt(SERVINGS);

            ArrayList<IngredientsItem> Ingredients = new ArrayList<IngredientsItem>();
            JSONArray ingredientsArray = recipeObject.getJSONArray(INGREDIENTS);

            for(int j = 0 ; j< ingredientsArray.length(); j++) {

                JSONObject ingredientsObject = ingredientsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                quantity = ingredientsObject.getDouble(QUANTITY);
                measure = ingredientsObject.getString(MEASURE);
                ingredient = ingredientsObject.getString(INGREDIENT);
                Ingredients.add(new IngredientsItem(quantity, measure, ingredient));
            }

            ArrayList<StepsItem> Steps = new ArrayList<StepsItem>();
            JSONArray stepsArray = recipeObject.getJSONArray(STEPS);

            for(int j = 0 ; j< stepsArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject stepsObject = stepsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                idSteps = recipeObject.getInt(IDSTEPS);
                shortDescription = stepsObject.getString(SHORTDESCRIPTION);
                description = stepsObject.getString(DESCRIPTION);
                videoURL = stepsObject.getString(VIDEOURL);
                thumbnailURL = stepsObject.getString(THUMBNAILURL);
                Steps.add(new StepsItem(idSteps, shortDescription, description, videoURL, thumbnailURL));
            }

            Baking.add(new BakingItem(id, name, servings, Ingredients, Steps));

            parsedRecipeData.add(new ArraysLists(Baking, Ingredients, Steps));

        }

        return parsedRecipeData;

    }
}
```

as you see there are 3 ArrayList classes:

1. `ArrayList<BakingItem>`
2. `ArrayList<IngredientsItem>`
3. `ArrayList<StepsItem>`

and this is the code for each one:

**BakingItem.java:**

```
    public class BakingItem implements Parcelable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int servings;
    private ArrayList<IngredientsItem> ingredients = new ArrayList<IngredientsItem>();
    private ArrayList<StepsItem> steps  = new ArrayList<StepsItem>();

    public BakingItem(int id, String name, int servings, ArrayList<IngredientsItem> ingredients, ArrayList<StepsItem> steps) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.servings = servings;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(id);
        out.writeString(name);
        out.writeInt(servings);
        out.writeTypedList(ingredients);
        out.writeTypedList(steps);
    }

    private BakingItem(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.servings = in.readInt();
        ingredients = new ArrayList<IngredientsItem>();
        in.readTypedList(ingredients, IngredientsItem.CREATOR);

    }

    public BakingItem() {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<BakingItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<BakingItem>() {
        @Override
        public BakingItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BakingItem(in);
        }
        @Override
        public BakingItem[] newArray(int i) {
            return new BakingItem[i];
        }
    };

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getServings() {
        return servings;
    }

}
```

**IngredientsItem.java:**

```
public class IngredientsItem implements Parcelable {

    private double quantity;
    private String measure;
    private String ingredient;

    public IngredientsItem(double quantity, String measure, String ingredient) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.measure = measure;
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeDouble(quantity);
        out.writeString(measure);
        out.writeString(ingredient);
    }

    private IngredientsItem(Parcel in) {
        this.quantity = in.readDouble();
        this.measure = in.readString();
        this.ingredient = in.readString();
    }

    public IngredientsItem() {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<IngredientsItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<IngredientsItem>() {
        @Override
        public IngredientsItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new IngredientsItem(in);
        }
        @Override
        public IngredientsItem[] newArray(int i) {
            return new IngredientsItem[i];
        }
    };

    public double getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public String getMeasure() {
        return measure;
    }

    public String getIngredient() {
        return ingredient;
    }

}
```

as well as the `StepsItem` class
and the forth is the ArraysLists.java which contain all the 3 arrays above and returned by the OpenBakingJsonUtils.java:

Then I'm trying to call these JSON data in different activities
so in **MainActivity.java** in `loadInBackground`:

```
Override
        public ArrayList<BakingItem> loadInBackground() {

            URL recipeRequestUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl();

            try {
                String jsonBakingResponse = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(recipeRequestUrl);

                ArrayList<ArraysLists> simpleJsonBakingData = OpenBakingJsonUtils.getSimpleBakingStringsFromJson(MainActivity.this, jsonBakingResponse);

                return simpleJsonBakingData;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I call the returned `ArrayList` from `OpenBakingJsonUtils.java` which is in this case the `ArraysLists`,
then in **DetailActivity.java** in `doInBackground`:

```
 @Override
    protected ArrayList<ArraysLists> doInBackground(Object... params) {
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        URL reviewsRequestUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl();

        try {
            String jsonReviewResponse = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(reviewsRequestUrl);

            ArrayList<ArraysLists> simpleJsonReviewData = OpenBakingJsonUtils.getSimpleBakingStringsFromJson(DetailsActivity.this, jsonReviewResponse);

            return simpleJsonReviewData;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

here I call the `ArrayList` of `ArraysLists` too but the problem in adapters of MainActivity.java and DetailsActivity.java in onBindViewHolder:

```
holder.CommentContent.setText(String.valueOf(mCommentsItems.get(position).getQuantity()));
```

it just says that cannot resolve method getQuantity() which is in IngredientsItem.java while I used the ArraysLists.java that returned by `OpenBakingJsonUtils.java`
so what should I do to call methods from BakingItem.java and IngredientsItem.java while I use the returned ArraysLists.java ?

Comment: use a map or other arraylist which will contain those three arraylist and return it.

Comment: You are creating your task more complex. Use JSON parser libraries like GSON, your task will be too easy.

Comment: you can use a class that has those array lists as its children then return that class

Comment: I think that your code is a mess. You should think what you trying to show in the DetailActivity, probabily you need a BakingItem Id, search for it in the BakingItem arraylist an then extract the IngredientItems arraylist of this BakingItem with something like: simpleJsonBakingData.get(0).getIngredientItems(). But your code have too many errors, you need accessors for IngrendtItem arraylist, you need to be able to search for the BakingItem...

Comment: @Amit you mean I should keep those 3 classes BakingItem.java and IngredientsItem.java and StepsItem.java but then create another class which contain my 3 classes then return this class right?

Comment: @mh9 yeah right... Like Item class which will contain those three objects..then you can return the Item class

Comment: @Amit okay I just edit the codes can you see it again please because I did what you suggest but I face new problem now

Comment: @mh9 just create a pojo class with three arrayList object..that's it